# Biholomorphism of a projective variety preserves the set of irreducible components

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Having a complex projective variety $X=\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$, where $X_\alpha$ are its irreducible components, is it true that an arbitrary biholomorphic map $\phi:X\rightarrow X$ sends its irreducible components to irreducible components (in some permutation of the set $A$)?

Comment: If biholomorphism means holmorphic bijection with holomorphic inverse, this is trivially true. What have you tried?

Comment: @KReiser It might be worth noting that the requirement "holomorphic inverse" is redundant.